# R: Parallel Coordinates Plot without GGally

Tags: r, ggplot2, plot, data-visualization, data-manipulation

I am using the R programming language. I am using a computer that does not have a USB port or an internet connection - I only have R with a few preloaded libraries (e.g. ggplot2, reshape2, dplyr, base R).

Is it possible to make "parallel coordinate" plots (e.g. below) using only the "ggplot2" library and not "ggally"?

```
#load libraries (I do not have GGally)
library(GGally)

#load data (I have MASS)
data(crabs, package = "MASS")

#make 2 different parallel coordinate plots
ggparcoord(crabs)
ggparcoord(crabs, columns = 4:8, groupColumn = "sex")
```

[image]

Thanks

Source: [https://homepage.divms.uiowa.edu/~luke/classes/STAT4580-2020/parcor.html](https://homepage.divms.uiowa.edu/%7Eluke/classes/STAT4580-2020/parcor.html)

Comment: just looks like a `geom_line` to me, what have you tried?

Comment: right now, I am trying to figure out a way to format the data so that I can use the geom_line

Comment: I think it might be possible with the plotly library as well: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65821992/r-plot-not-fully-loading

Comment: Looking at the [source code for ggparcoord](https://rdrr.io/cran/GGally/src/R/ggparcoord.R) there are a few steps before `geom_line()`, such as scaling the data and imputing missing values. Should be possible to replicate, but it will take a bit of effort.

Comment: @jared_mamrot: i wonder if this will work by copy and pasting the source code...

Comment: @Noob copy/pasting the source code would be the first thing I'd try. At some point you'll need to convert your data into a long format - looks like `ggparcoord` uses `reshape::melt` for that. Not sure if you have that package available - if not, look for other options at the [wide to long FAQ](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2185252/903061).

Comment: thank you - I will see if "geom_line()" can be combined with the "melt()" function from reshape2.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In fact, you do not even need `ggplot`! This is just a plot of standardised values (minus mean divided by SD), so you can implement this logic with any plotting function capable of doing so. The cleanest and easiest way to do it is in steps in base R:

[image]

```
# Standardising the variables of interest
data(crabs, package = "MASS")
crabs[, 4:8] <- apply(crabs[, 4:8], 2, scale)
# This colour solution works in great generality, although RColorBrewer has better distinct schemes
mycolours <- rainbow(length(unique(crabs$sex)), end = 0.6)
# png("gally.png", 500, 400, type = "cairo", pointsize = 14)
par(mar = c(4, 4, 0.5, 0.75))
plot(NULL, NULL, xlim = c(1, 5), ylim = range(crabs[, 4:8]) + c(-0.2, 0.2),
     bty = "n", xaxt = "n", xlab = "Variable", ylab = "Standardised value")
axis(1, 1:5, labels = colnames(crabs)[4:8])
abline(v = 1:5, col = "#00000033", lwd = 2)
abline(h = seq(-2.5, 2.5, 0.5), col = "#00000022", lty = 2)
for (i in 1:nrow(crabs)) lines(as.numeric(crabs[i, 4:8]), col = mycolours[as.numeric(crabs$sex[i])])
legend("topright", c("Female", "Male"), lwd = 2, col = mycolours, bty = "n")
# dev.off()
```

You can apply this logic (x axis with integer values, y axis with standardised variable lines) in any package that can conveniently draw multiple lines (as in time series), but this solution has no extra dependencies an will not become unavailable due to an orphaned package with 3 functions getting purged from CRAN.

Comment: spasiba! this answer is perfect! I had a question relating to your answer - should I post it in a new question?

Comment: Can you please take a look at this related question? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65851678/r-error-in-funxi-only-defined-on-a-data-frame-with-all-numeric-var thank you

Comment: @Noob There you go.

Comment: Thank you so much for your help! Everything is so elegant and beautiful!

Comment: I am working on this question over here: perhaps you might have some ideas?

Comment: @Noob Which question? What kind of ideas? Estimation of models on a computer without Internet connection? Just write down the criterion (i. e. penalty function or log-likelihood function) and optimise it with `optim`.

Comment: Sorry - i meant this question here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65864333/identifying-points-by-color

Answer (score 0):

The closest thing I found to this without the "GGally" was the built in function using the "MASS" library:

```
#source: https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/MASS/html/parcoord.html
library(MASS)
parcoord(state.x77[, c(7, 4, 6, 2, 5, 3)])

ir <- rbind(iris3[,,1], iris3[,,2], iris3[,,3])
parcoord(log(ir)[, c(3, 4, 2, 1)], col = 1 + (0:149)%/%50)
```

Comment: If you have the MASS package available, see https://stackoverflow.com/a/65836675/12957340