# R: Plot not Fully Loading

Tags: r, plotly, data-visualization, data-manipulation

I am working the R programming language. I am trying to follow this tutorial over here: https://plotly.com/r/parallel-coordinates-plot/

I am trying to make a "parallel coordinate plot" of the famous iris data set.

Instead of loading the iris data set through the github link, I tried to use the built in iris data set that is available in R:

```
#load library
library(plotly)

#load data
data(iris)
df = iris


#make plot
fig <- df %>% plot_ly(type = 'parcoords', line = list(color = ~Species, colorscale = list(c(0,'red'),c(0.5,'green'),c(1,'blue'))), dimensions = list( list(range = c(2,4.5), label = 'Sepal Width', values = ~Sepal.Width), list(range = c(4,8), constraintrange = c(5,6), label = 'Sepal Length', values = ~Sepal.Length), list(range = c(0,2.5), label = 'Petal Width', values = ~Petal.Width), list(range = c(1,7), label = 'Petal Length', values = ~Petal.Length) ) )  

#view plot
fig
```

However, this produces an incomplete plot:

[image]

Does anyone know why these two plots are different and how can I fix this?
Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The data used in the tutorial has an additional column `species_id` which is an integer column unique for every species. The default `iris` dataset does not have that so you can convert the `Species` column which is factor to integer.

```
library(plotly)

iris %>% plot_ly(type = 'parcoords', line = list(color = ~as.integer(Species), 
         colorscale = list(c(0,'red'),c(0.5,'green'),c(1,'blue'))), 
         dimensions = list( list(range = c(2,4.5), label = 'Sepal Width', values = ~Sepal.Width), 
                      list(range = c(4,8), constraintrange = c(5,6), label = 'Sepal Length', values = ~Sepal.Length), 
                      list(range = c(0,2.5), label = 'Petal Width', values = ~Petal.Width), 
                      list(range = c(1,7), label = 'Petal Length', values = ~Petal.Length) ) )
```

[image]

Comment: thank you for your reply. why does "species" have to be a "integer" and not "factor"?

Comment: if i want all the lines to be the same color (remove "species"), will the following modification work? 
iris %>% plot_ly(type = 'parcoords', 
               dimensions = list( list(range = c(2,4.5), label = 'Sepal Width', values = ~Sepal.Width), 
                                  list(range = c(4,8), constraintrange = c(5,6), label = 'Sepal Length', values = ~Sepal.Length), 
                                  list(range = c(0,2.5), label = 'Petal Width', values = ~Petal.Width), 
                                  list(range = c(1,7), label = 'Petal Length', values = ~Petal.Length) ) )

Comment: I guess that is what plotly expects for the `color` attribute. I don't use `plotly` much though but that was the difference between the data in the tutorial and default `iris` dataset.

Comment: Can you please take a look at this question if you have time? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68242473/r-adding-a-tool-tip-to-interactive-plot-plotly thank you